# Drupal 7 custom url path for search in view

Tags: drupal-7

I have a search functionality in Drupal 7. I have created it using views. In the page settings section I have "**The menu path or URL of this view** " of the view set as /my-car-listing/.

[image: Car Search View]

The search url when appended  to the url look like this:

```
www.mysite.com/my-car-listing?cartype=3&price=5000.
```

I get the search results for this when I search from the `my-car-listing` page.

But when I create a block for the search and add it to the sidebar, there is some problem. The search query, that is ?cartype=3&price=5000 is appended to the current url and is not working. It just reloads the current page.

The search works if I use the particular url I specified above.

I need some help for fixing this issue.

Comment: What modules do you have installed? Pathauto, Search API, Custom Search, Facet API, ...? There are plenty ways to make something similar work. Also, how do you define the block, is it a Views Exposed Filters Block?

Comment: I have a view page for the custom content type I have created. I did not have Pathauto installed. I have Search module and Search API. But I am not using it.The view is using exposed filters. I have the "Filter Criteria" set for the content type. I have the block settings to display it on all pages.